# 2D Greedy Ascent Search Algorithm Clarification

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I am doing some remedial work on algorithms as I am taking a graduate course on them in the Fall and was a physics undergrad. Watching this [video](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-1-algorithmic-thinking-peak-finding/) and at the 38:00 mark he goes over the greedy ascent algorithm for a 2D array. I am confused as he defines the peak as 
a <= b,c,d,e (with b,c,d and e being the elements to the left,right,top,bottom of the current element 'a'). And then he goes on to say that to find the peak you follow the greatest element bordering on 'a' but what if you have the 2D array:

20 15 13
12  10 10
40 40 40

and started at 13, wouldn't the greedy ascent algorithm incorrectly identify 20 as the peak? How can you search an unsorted array without having to look at every element?

I thank you for your help apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay close attention to the definitions, as they are not the same as what you would expect intuitively.

> he defines the peak as a <= b,c,d,e (with b,c,d and e being the elements to the left,right,top,bottom of the current element 'a')

So there you have it -- a peak is defined as a *local* maximum (an element larger than all of its immediate neighbors), rather than a *global* maximum (an element larger than all other elements). By this definition, it's clear that while 20 is not **the** largest element it is **a** peak.

(As noted in comments, the definition should probably be a **>=** b,c,d,e that's probably just a typo in the original post)

Comment: isn't is a >= b,c,d,e?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the video and the problem statement says:-
find a peak if it exists.
And according to the definition it is guaranteed that there will always be a peak.
A Peak does not have to be a GLOBAL maximum according to the definition. Coming to the next point:-
how can you search an unsorted array without having to look at every element?
Well you cannot do that if it is unsorted because potentially every element could be the one which you are looking for but, When I correlate your question to the peak finding problem then he is using a greedy approach to find an element which satisfies a specific condition rather than looking for any specific element in the array . By using a Greedy approach we hope to find it earlier but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also taking that course and peak as he defines it is, an element say 'a' that is greater than any element bordering it.

[image: Greedy Ascent Algorithm]

here, 'a' may or may not be global peak [bigger than all elements in the matrix]. what ever the algorithm finds faster it will give that to us provided it matches the conditions above.

There is some confusion about what peak finding is actually finding. It is easily mistaken as the biggest element in the array/matrix but really depends on the question being asked. If the question doesn't specify what peak is, it is generally taken to be the element abiding by above conditions waiting to be found by an algorithm.

Look at this:
[Greedy Ascent Algorithm GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Greedy-search-path-example.gif)